# robotium pressMenuItem or clickOnMenuItem not working

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

I use SherlockActionBar. I have 3 menu entries. 1st is always shown, the others have text and no icons so they are in menu.
I run the test several times. First time it works pretty good but the other times it fails because of

```
04-19 16:43:14.326: D/Robotium(22310): 'Disable layers' not found. Have found: 'Layer_3'
04-19 16:43:15.247: I/TestRunner(22310): ----- begin exception -----
04-19 16:43:15.267: I/TestRunner(22310): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Text string: 'Disable layers' is not found!
04-19 16:43:15.267: I/TestRunner(22310):    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
04-19 16:43:15.267: I/TestRunner(22310):    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
04-19 16:43:15.267: I/TestRunner(22310):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnText(Clicker.java:339)
04-19 16:43:15.267: I/TestRunner(22310):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickOnMenuItem(Clicker.java:199)
04-19 16:43:15.267: I/TestRunner(22310):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clickOnMenuItem(Solo.java:763)
```

pressMenuItem produces the same result.
Why it can't access the menu during the secound launch? The menu even isn't opened. It's strange..

EDITED:
I use last robotium 4.1.
Code:

```
        View imageBehind = solo.getView(R.id.image_view_behind);
        View imageTop = solo.getView(R.id.image_view_top);
        solo.clickOnMenuItem(solo.getString(R.string.disable_sbl));
        assertTrue(imageBehind.getVisibility() == View.GONE);
        solo.clickOnMenuItem(solo.getString(R.string.disable_stl));
        assertTrue(imageTop.getVisibility() == View.GONE);
        solo.clickOnMenuItem(solo.getString(R.string.enable_sbl));
        assertTrue(imageBehind.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
        solo.clickOnMenuItem(solo.getString(R.string.enable_stl));
        assertTrue(imageTop.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Which version of robotium are you using ? Can you share the test code? If not , have you tried with clickOnMenuItem(actual, false); ?

Comment: It looks like a timing issue to me . Can know more if you reply back to my original queries .

Comment: Why this issue **always** happened on the second test?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timing issue , that's very much prevalent. Once your menu is up, it disappears during the subsequent times. Adding

```
    solo.waitForText("Menu item");
```

before

```
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("Menu item");
```

might solve the problem.  But you need to do this for all the click actions , i think.
Let me know. I am also eager to know if it solves this .

Comment: @Metalex : I understand that the answer provided resolved your problem. I was not entirely sure, as this did not happen to me in my version of robotium. So sheers mate .

Answer (score -1):

if it is not working intermittently,90% of the cases it will be timing issue so please use sleep api in between clikcing of menu items

solo.sleep(2000);